# postgresql function returns multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am confused about the passing process of the parameter from functions created in Postgres:

```
create type IncorrectRecord as (pattern_number integer, uoc_number integer);

create or replace function text1(pattern text, uoc_threshold integer) 
    returns  setof IncorrectRecord
as $$
begin
return next count(v1.code) as pattern_number, count(v2.code) as uoc_number
from (select * from q1_1 where code like pattern) as v1, (select
 * from q1_1 where code like pattern and uoc > uoc_threshold) as v2;
return;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I have modified some, there is no parameters errors but it still does not work.
when I tested it with

```
select * 
from test1('ECO%', 8)
```

> error:  function returns two columns.

Is there any thing wrong with the type? How can I fix it?.

Comment: `returns IncorrectRecord` -  What is `IncorrectRecord`?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the pair of values, where first one is the count where `code like pattern` and the second one is the count where `code like pattern and uoc > uoc_threshold` - you are using the wrong approach. Answering to your question, in short, it is impossible to use parameters in DDLs.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? Looks awfully similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735008/postgresql-functions

Answer (score 1):

As the message says you are returning two columns. Return a composite type instead:

```
return next (
    count(v1.code) as pattern_number, count(v2.code) as uoc_number
)::IncorrectRecord
```