# Postgresql functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

These are the type definitions provided to me

```
create type IR as (pattern_number integer, uoc_number integer);
```

My current progress is:

```
create or replace function q1(pattern text, uoc_threshold integer)
  returns setof IR
  as $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    select count(code) from temp where code like $1;
    RETURN QUERY 
    select count(code) from temp where code like $1 and uoc > $2;

  END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

My output needs to be like this :
Query:-

```
select * 
from q1('ECO%', 6);

pattern_number  |   uoc_number 
80              |         5
```

I get an error saying:

> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
>   DETAIL:  Returned type bigint does not match expected type integer in column 1.
>   
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function q1(text,integer) line 3 at RETURN QUERY

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your function returns two rows with a single (bigint) column. You want a single row with a single column that is a record.

Comment: do I get it right? you want `select count(code) from temp where code like $1` as pattern_number  and `select count(code) from temp where code like $1 and uoc > $2` as uoc_number ?.. I added answer with code - sic?

Comment: @VaoTsun Yes. That is exactly what I want but your answer seems to not resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?..

```
create or replace function q1(pattern text, uoc_threshold integer)
  returns setof IR
  as $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    select (select count(code) from temp where code like $1)::integer
    ,(
    select count(code) from temp where code like $1 and uoc > $2)::integer;

  END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: You got it right but the error is still there. It is the same exact error.